# Change the email signature in Outlook 2007 based on the recipient

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook-2007, email-signature

I work for an international company and work with people speaking a lot of different languages. When I email people who speak another language it would be nice if my email signature would automatically change based on the recipient or the recipient's domain.

Does anybody know if there is any sort of functionality within Outlook or a third-party plug-in which can provide this?

Comment: I'm not expert, but you may be able to do this with a macro, though you'll probably want to mention what version of outlook you have so that people can help.

Comment: Thanks...I'm using Outlook 2007 running Windows 7 32-bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First, setup up your most used signature (and most used title) as the default signature. You can create your signature by going to Tools\Options and then clicking the Mail Format tab. Click the Signature button near the bottom and you'll be presented with a dialog window where you can create new signatures. Create one now and it will become your main (or default signature).
2. Then create another signature (e.g., with a different title) and save it under a different signature name. For example, if your default is "User English," then call your alternative something like "User Spanish."
3. Now when you start a new email, your default signature will appear in the email window. To use your alternate signature, right-click over the signature and you will see a pop-up menu with the two signature choices. Choose "User Spanish" and you'll see your alternate signature replace the default one. You can create multiple (more than two) signatures if you wish.

Comment: I appreciate this, and it may well be helpful to somebody else, but it's not the answer I was looking for.

I already know how to setup multiple signatures and how to change them. I'm looking for something to do this automatically based on their email domain...i.e. if I'm emailing xyz@abc.ru and everybody with an email address @abc.ru speaks Russian, then I would like it to automatically change to that signature. Your way works but sometimes I forget to change my signature before firing off an email.